# Portal 2 Offline Co-op on Mac

Tags: portal-2

Has anyone had any luck playing portal 2 offline co-op on Mac? My controls are messed up for controller 2 (xbox controllers) and it seems like it's not only my problem. Any tips on how to get it working?

Comment: What have you tried? You mentioned others are having the same problem, can you point us to where you were finding this? it might help us offer more relevant answers

Comment: Here you go:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/620/discussions/0/828923952140890800/